# Is there any API to create email audit monitor in outlook?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

`G-Suite` has an email audit api where admin can create an audit monitor on the source user. All the emails `TO` and `FROM` source user will be forwarded to destination user in `MIME` format. Does outlook also have any such API's to audit emails? I went through the documentation and looks like it's just audit logs but not email forwarding. I am pretty new to outlook and this feature is very critical to developing our `Add-in`.

Any help around this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you rephrase please? What exactly do you want to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins)  . Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.